# SS2.0 Set/Update Script Deployment Schedule fields via SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Hope someone can help me out here.
I've been working on updating/creating Script Deployment records via SuiteScript, and haven't been able to find a lot of information on it, so I've just been treating it like any other Record script.

*(In Scheduled Script)*

However, setting or updating the Schedule fields does not appear to work.
Regardless of any logic applied to those fields, no change is made and no system notes recorded.

Can someone help?
Many thanks!
Cheers, Giles

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the NetSuite Records Browser for the Script Deployment record shows that the schedule fields are not accessible via SuiteScript: https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/script/record/scriptdeployment.html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Pierre Plourde
I'll keep digging because there has to be some way of specifying this, especially when deploying a bundle for example

Comment: Deploying a bundle isn't done via SuiteScript, but using either the SuiteBundler or the SuiteCloud SDK. Neither of those requires the field to be accessible to SuiteScript since they work very differently (using the NS UI or using XML, respectively).